# TRIM support on Intel RS2BL080 Hardware RAID card?

Tags: ssd, raid, raid-0, hardware-raid

I've got an Intel RS2BL080 hardware RAID card and I'd like to know if it supports TRIM on my RAID-0 array of SSDs. I've heard that the Intel 7 series *integrated* RAID solutions that ship with motherboards supports TRIM, but I'm not sure if that applies to their high-end hardware cards. The driver version is 12.12.0-0124. Does anyone know if this is supported or if there's a way I could find out easily?